# auto-submit an upload form when a file is selected with php?

Tags: php, html, forms, input, file-upload

i have a simple `upload profile avatar form` in my own website and i want to make it upload automatically after selecting an image..
i tried using `onchange()`

js:

```
document.getElementById("file").onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById("form").submit();
};
```

Jquery:

```
$('#file').change(function() {
  $('#target').submit();
});
```

html:

```
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="form.submit()">
```

but for some weird reasons it doesn't work with my `upload.php` page, after choosing the file it just redirect to upload.php without making it's code to work which shows a blank page..

in case this is my `upload.php` code:

```
<?php

include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
include_once 'includes/vars.inc.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $fileNAME = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTYPE = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $fileTMPNM = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileERROR = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileSIZE = $_FILES['file']['size'];


    $fileEXT = explode('.', $fileNAME);
    $fileACTUALEXT = strtolower(end($fileEXT));

    $fileALLOWED = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

    if (in_array($fileACTUALEXT, $fileALLOWED)) {
        if ($fileERROR === 0) {
            if ($fileSIZE < 5000000) {
                $fileNEWNAME = $userUID."-avatar.".$fileACTUALEXT;
                $fileROOT = 'content/uploads/'.$fileNEWNAME;
                move_uploaded_file($fileTMPNM, $fileROOT);
                $sql = "UPDATE user_meta SET um_avatar_status=0 WHERE um_user_id='$userID';";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                header('Location: '.$siteurl.'/user/'.$userUID.'?editavatar=success');
            } else {
                echo "The file you are trying to upload is TOO big!";
            }

        } else {
            echo "Oops! there was an unknown ERROR, please try again later.";
        }

    } else {
        echo "you can't upload this type of files!";
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: what is ur form code looks like

Comment: did you specify the form action="upload.php" , method="POST" and the <form id="target"

Comment: yes i did.
`<form id='upload-avatar' action='upload.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>`

Comment: your form id should be $('#upload-avatar').submit();

Comment: i am just showing you an examle above i did changed the `id` but i get the same results, can it be a problem from my `upload.php` page?

Comment: could be, please show your upload.php

Comment: i added it above please take  a look at it..

Comment: first comment out all the code after if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   and try echo "test". if you can successfully see "test". then let me know

Comment: still a blank page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change  This part `if (isset($_file['submit'])) {` with`if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {`

> $_POST contains all the data from forms (except files).
>
> $_FILES contains all files sent to server via forms (only from )

```
 <?php

   include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
   include_once 'includes/vars.inc.php';

    if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {


        $file = $_FILES['file'];

        $fileNAME = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $fileTYPE = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $fileTMPNM = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $fileERROR = $_FILES['file']['error'];
        $fileSIZE = $_FILES['file']['size'];


        $fileEXT = explode('.', $fileNAME);
        $fileACTUALEXT = strtolower(end($fileEXT));

        $fileALLOWED = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

        if (in_array($fileACTUALEXT, $fileALLOWED)) {
            if ($fileERROR === 0) {
                if ($fileSIZE < 5000000) {
                    $fileNEWNAME = $userUID."-avatar.".$fileACTUALEXT;
                    $fileROOT = 'content/uploads/'.$fileNEWNAME;
                    move_uploaded_file($fileTMPNM, $fileROOT);
                    $sql = "UPDATE user_meta SET um_avatar_status=0 WHERE um_user_id='$userID';";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    header('Location: '.$siteurl.'/user/'.$userUID.'?editavatar=success');
                } else {
                    echo "The file you are trying to upload is TOO big!";
                }

            } else {
                echo "Oops! there was an unknown ERROR, please try again later.";
            }

        } else {
            echo "you can't upload this type of files!";
        }

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: copy and paste this in upload.php

Comment: thanks! it worked very well!
so what's the diffrence between 
`if (isset($_file['submit'])) {` &
`if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {` ?

Comment: $_POST contains all the data from forms (except files).

$_FILES contains all files sent to server via forms (only from <input type="file" />)

Answer (score 0):

Add this on top of upload.php to see php errors, It will be useful for you to track down where the error is occurring in

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: i solved it by the answer from **devil**, but thank you anyway